# Hedging Curve Risk with Futures

Tags: fixed-income, futures, duration, hedge, rates

Please help confirm/correct my understanding of hedging curve risk using futures.

For example, if I purchased a 9y bond and hedged the duration risk (parallel shift) by shorting 10y treasury futures making net DV01 equal to zero, I would still have curve risk (e.g. risk of 9s10s steepening). If I could only hedge using 5y and 10y treasury futures due to liquidity, how do I calculate how many 5y futures and additional 10y futures are needed to hedge the 9s10s curve risk?

I understand that I need to use modified duration – would the below method be correct?

(9y modified duration * notional) - (10y future modified duration * notional) = 9s10s curve DV01

(5y future modified duration * notional) - (10y future modified duration * notional) = 5s10s curve DV01

Curve Hedge Ratio = 9s10s curve DV01 / 5s10s curve DV01

Comment: You're thinking of "key rate duratoin", not "modified duratoin". However if you just purge the word "duration" from your vocabulary and instead try to minimize the P&L from a 1 basis point change in benchmark rates, then the picture will immediately become more clear.

Comment: You might want to consider the CTD. "10y futures" commonly refers to ZN aka TY which has a CTD closer to 7y in maturity. The "ultra" 10y future has a CTD closer to 10y in maturity.